# compiler automata , how do I make this diagram so the lines wouldn't intersect?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-construction, artificial-intelligence, diagram

I am writing a Java app that helps transform a non deterministic automata to a deterministic one ( im translating from french ) . Well the algorithm that does that isnt the problem , since there are rules to follow .

But i'm having trouble figuring out how the GUI would work ... i figured out how to draw the circles and arrows and all ( its not complete yet but im not asking about that ). What i'm asking here is how would i be able to write a program that figures out which circle should be drawn where , so the diagram would look well drawn with no intersections :

[image]

So what i want is for it to come out like the one on the left .Intersection isnt the main problem , just how the program would firgure out the layout in the first place.

now i know usually i should post some codes and show effort and all but the part that i have coded already i dont have any problems with as ive said... the auto drawing part  is the first time i come onto something where i don't even know what to try and code :/ I brainstormed about this for quite some time to no avail . thought about layouts , recursive algorithms , AI algorithms ... i just don't know what im looking for here.

Is there some kind of trick to it ? cuz ive seen this in other programs before. Is there any information i seem to be missing ? anything i could read to help with this would be much appretiated .

Comment: The term you are looking for, here is _planar_ drawing. Not all graphs are planar and can be drawn with no intersections. [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/yfiles)'s orthogonal layout algorithm will draw all planar graphs without intersections, however this sometimes looks worse than simpler drawings with a few intersections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use existing libs. For example, [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_about.html).

Comment: That actually pointed me out in the right direction , although its not open source or free ... I now at least know what im looking for , I think i'll end up using JUNG http://jung.sourceforge.net/